# Clearcase find command prerequisites

Tags: find, clearcase

How do I use `cleartool find` to search a bare vob? Must I always first define a view?

I typically use CCRC and in this case I am looking for a list of all files of a certain branch type.

**EDIT:**

[This page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm) says:

> Typically, you start with all objects in a directory tree as seen in
>   your view. You can also start with all objects in one or more VOBs,
>   regardless of they are visible in a particular view.

I'm looking for information on the version of the command that the second sentence describes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use cleartool in a CCRC setting.
CCRC (ClearCase Remote Client) is a light-weight ClearCase installation which communicates with a CCRC server (which, in turn, talk to a full ClearCase Vob server).

You can use [rcleartool, the CCRC CLI](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24021929), but it doesn't include a `find` comnand.

'[`cleartool find`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm)' itself is always used in a view, because it needs a path (to at least a Vob).

> You can also start with all objects in one or more VOBs, regardless of they are visible in a particular view.

That doesn't mean you can use cleartool find outside a view.

The two pages giving *a lot* of examples are:

- [SAMECS find examples](http://www.samecs.com/commands/cleartool%20commands/find/find.htm)
- [IBM additional find examples](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425)

The SAMECS link and the cleartool man page are clear:

```
-avobs
```

> By default, `find` starts with all the elements, branches, and versions in all the VOBs mounted on the local host.
>   **In a snapshot view**, `find –avobs` issues a warning if all mounted VOBs have not been loaded into the view.
>   This option depends on the MVFS and is ignored on hosts that do not support dynamic views.
>   **You must be in a view context to use find `–avobs`**.
>   If the `CLEARCASE_AVOBS` EV is set to a colon-separated list of VOB tags (in UNIX; in Windows, list items must be separated by semicolons), this set of VOBs is used instead.

In short, to access any vob content, they must be loaded (snapshot *view*) or mounted (dynamic *view*). In both cases, even though the find is not restricted by the view confi spec (especially in the case of the `-avobs` option), a view is still needed to run `cleartool find`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I use cleartool (and CCRC) everyday. It is possible to use find outside a view?

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod OK. Then no. If you want to find files, you need a view. I have edited the answer.

Comment: VonC, I added additional info to this question. Can you please take a look again?

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod sure. I have edited the answer to add details and links.