# Formatting Clearcase cleartool find output

Tags: find, clearcase, cleartool

In the context of a dynamic "default view" when I issue the following commands:

`$ cd Dir_A/Dir_B`

`$ ct find . -all -nvi -type f -ele 'brtype(my_branch)' -print`

For each line I get strange output that looks like this:

```
/vobs/vob_name/Dir_A/Dir_B@@/main/Branch_A/Branch_B/n1/Dir_C/main/Branch_C/n2/Dir_D/main/Branch_D/n3/Filename@@
```

How do I get the find command to simply print the standard operating system pathname without all the intermediate version information for each directory?

I have tried `-exec 'ct des -fmt'` to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That strange format is called an **[extended path name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/988904/6309)**.
As [explained here](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/pathnames_ccase.htm), a result like:

```
\proj_vob\foo.c@@\main\bugfix\4
```

is actually called a **version-extended path name**.

In your case:

```
/vobs/vob_name/Dir_A/Dir_B@@/main/Branch_A/Dir_C/[...]/n3/Filename@@
```

is a **vob extended path name**.

It references elements (file or directory) which are no longer visible in the view (because they have been rmnamed, that is removed).

> You can access any version of an element by using its version ID, which specifies its exact version-tree location.

That allows to access versions which aren't visible in the view (i.e. selected by the config spec of the view) in which you are executing a `cleartool find` (since [a view is a requirement for a find](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17435684/6309)).

---

Try also the `-nxname` option:

```
ct find . -all -nvi -nxname -type f -ele "brtype(my_branch)" -print
```

(but that would remove only the final `@@`)

---

[fmt_ccase](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm) has some way to format it, but you can also try (as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6043443/6309)):

```
-exec "echo %CLEARCASE_PN%"
```

(Here it doesn't work, since there is no "path name" available for the version found: the view doesn't select it directly, so that version isn't visible, and `%CLEARCASE_PN%` is set to `%CLEARCASE_XPN%`, the extended path name).

Check also what the Leaf name returns:

```
-exec "cleartool  descr -fmt \"%Ln\" \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\""
```

But that only returns the file name, not its path.

---

If you need a simple path (which won't represent an "actual" path, because those elements are not all visible in the view), you would need to process each line in order to remove `/main/.../n1`, leaving only `Dir_C\dir_D\element`.

Here is one library which is suppose to do that: [ClearCase-Tools](http://help-site.com/Programming/Languages/Perl/CPAN/Development_Support/ClearCase_Full/ClearCase-Tools/CanonPath.pm/)

```
 $explicitPath = '/vobTag/users/.@@/main/1/llf/main/12/install/main/1/README/main/2';
 $canonPath = ClearCase::Vob::CanonPath->parse( $explicitPath );
 $canonPath = $cpathObj->parse( $explicitPath );
```

> Where `$canonPath` will, in this example, contain the following string:

```
 /vobTag/users/llf/install/README
```

You can find the [sources in those rpm](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=perl%28ClearCase::Vob::CanonPath%29), in `usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.6.1/ClearCase/Vob/CanonPath.pm`.

The implementation isn't trivial, but it is doable: very small extract:

```perl
push @branches, "main";
while (@leaves && !(($leaves[0] =~ "^[0-9]+\$") || ($leaves[0] =~ "^CHECKEDOUT\.[0-9]+\$"))) {
  $leaf = shift(@leaves);
  push @branches, $leaf if defined($leaf);
  $self->dpr("dump(3) $leaf")     if defined($leaf);
}
```

Comment: The first command returns the same extended pathname with the version info attached to the intermediate directories. The second command returns the filename, with no path. I just need the OS pathname for each element. I do not understand why this is so difficult.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod it is "so difficult" because a find -all will look into all the history of all vobs, meaning the results won't be visible/accessible from a view (hence the extended pathname, which is actually accessible from any dynamic view). "Accessible" means that if you do a "type \simple\path\result", it will return "not found". Those result are not directly visible in the view. I have edited the answer to add more informations.